# Docker logs driver gcplogs: How to format logs so that they're shown correctly in Stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

tldr:
- I'm writing logs from a python application that's running outside of Google Cloud
- I'm using [gcplogs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gcplogs/) to import logs to Stackdriver
- Logs imported must be in the wrong format because they're not displayed as they should in Stackdriver logging

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to configure the gcplogs Docker logs driver so that logs appear as they should in Stackdriver logging. Here's what the logs currently look like:
[image]

It looks like stackdriver isn't parsing these logs correctly. However, if the docker image is ran in GKE, the logs look correct:

[image]

Here Stackdriver has recognized that these logs were debug messages.

Since these two applications are using the same logger, I think the message that is logged from the application is in the right format, and that it must be the gcplogs configuration that's wrong or missing something. ([See this repository for what the python code looks like](https://github.com/cognitedata/python-logs-export-docker-gcplogs-test))

Here's the content of `/etc/docker/daemon.json` on the machine that's running the Docker image:

```
{
  "log-driver": "gcplogs",
  "log-opts": {
    "gcp-project": "removed",
    "env": "host"
  }
}
```

The output of `docker info | grep 'Logging Driver'` is `Logging Driver: gcplogs`.

The output of `docker version` is:

```
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    0520e24
 Built: Wed Mar 21 23:05:52 2018
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   0520e24
  Built:        Wed Mar 21 23:14:54 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Any tips on how to configure this so that the logs end up looking as they should in Stackdriver would be much appreciated.

Comment: gcplogs agent is older and less malleable, hence may I confirm if you have tried with the Stackdriver agent to export the logs to Stackdriver? https://medium.com/tendozen/google-cloud-platform-logging-monitoring-v2-with-docker-91c398999add

Comment: Also see the following documentation on "Collecting Docker Log Files with Fluentd and sending to GCP." https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/tree/master/fluentd-gcp-image

Comment: Get 404 when trying to access repo `github.com/cognitedata/python-logs-export-docker-gcplogs-test`. Is it private?

Comment: @YaguraStation I'm sorry about that. I created the repository within the GitHub organization of my previous employer. I no longer have access to it.